# How to properly and reliably save fragment state (custom classes)

Tags: android, android-fragments, state

how can i properly save fragment state, so that its 100% reliable?

My problem is, when i take picture in my fragment, it causes my app to be killed and recreated. State of my fragment is lost.

I have tried `onSaveInstanceState` which to my surprise didnt work, if app is killed after taking picture, state is lost `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` savedInstanceState is null...

I have tried having state variables as static. Firstly, i dont like this solution, secondly it dont work in my special case since i have multiple instances of fragment class across application.

What is recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using SharedPreferences. Have a look at this question. [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Or you can create an Sqlite database to persist your state. Since you have custom classes I'm guessing thats what you will have use.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

I don't recommend using static variables in your app because they can get flushed if the system is low on memory.